# Maximum of minimum distance to a point cloud

Tags: algorithms

I have $N$ 2D points $P_i$ in a rectangle $T$. 
I'd like to compute a coverage score defined as

$$
\max_{x \in T} \min_{0 < i \leq N} \operatorname{distance}(x,P_i) 
$$

How can I do that efficiently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V_i$ be the Voronoi region w.r.t to $P_i$ and $R_i$ be the distance of the most distant vertex of $V_i$ from $P_i$, then
$$
\max_{x\in T}\min_{i\in\{1,\ldots,N\}} d(x,P_i) = \max_{i\in\{1,\ldots,N\}} R_i.
$$

Comment: Very nice, I didn't know about Voronoi diagrams. Thanks !